# Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server

Tags: jenkins

I'm currently facing an issue with my Jenkins Continuous Integration (CI) server and could really use some guidance in troubleshooting and resolving it.

**Problem:**
When attempting to start Jenkins, I encounter the error message: "Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server."

```
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: Stopped Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 01 14:10:30 www.domain.com systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

**Additional Details:**

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Jenkins Version: [Specify the version of Jenkins you are using, e.g., 2.303.2, 2.320, etc.]

Java Version:

```
java -version
openjdk version "17-ea" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17-ea+11-Ubuntu-116.042)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17-ea+11-Ubuntu-116.042, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Jenkins Version:

```
jenkins --version
jenkins: invalid Java version: java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

(It's showing the message 'invalid Java version.' I attempted to change the Java version by modifying the JAVA_HOME value, but I was unable to change it.)

Steps Taken:

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue, but unfortunately, none of them have worked:

1. Verified that Java is installed and correctly set in the system PATH.
2. Changed port and ensured that there are no conflicting processes running on the Jenkins default port
3. Attempted to restart the Jenkins service multiple times.

Reviewed the Jenkins documentation and searched online for similar issues, but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.